# VB.Net WebKitBrowser Enter key issue

Tags: vb.net, webkit

I'm programming with vb.net 2012 and I'm having an issue with the WebKit.Net framework.

After my webkitbrowser object has loaded a page, I enter in login credentials, now the tab button gets hooked fine but when I hit enter (like people normally do on websites to login rather than actually hitting the login button) it keeps focus on another form object (tab index 0) and hits enter on that, it doesn't hook the enter button to the webkitbrowser.

I have added the following but it hasn't worked.

```
Private Sub WebKitBrowser2_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles WebKitBrowser2.MouseClick
    Me.WebKitBrowser2.Focus()
End Sub
```

I'm hoping someone has a solution to this issue?